# reduce number to nearest multiple of 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We are trying to make the input divisible by 3, for example if 9 is entered, the program works fine. If 7 is entered, the program displays the result in decimals... so what we wish to do is:

if the input is 7, the program will deduct 1 from the total and act as if it were a six( which is, of course, divisible by 3).

Comment: Why not just round or truncate the result?

Comment: You could even mod it by three and then subtract the result of the mod

Comment: Ok thank you for that , we'll give it a try!

Comment: If Else condition. If x/3 = integer, return. Else, x-1.

Answer (score 4):

```
var input = 7;
var adjusted = (input - (input % 3)); 

var test = adjusted / 3;            // Yay, no decimals!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mod to determine the remainder and then subtract it from the number like below.

```
var number = 7;
var difference = 7 % 3;

number -= difference;
```